# Python code keeps return unexpected indent error although indentation appears to be consistent, no mixed spaces/tabs

Tags: python

The beginning of my for loop is returning the error. All indentation has been done with tabs. I've checked and there are no spaces mixed with tabs.

*EDIT*
I'm editing to include the entire code, per request, because it looks like the error isn't in the for loop on line 29, although that's where the error is point to. As mentioned before, I've check to make sure all indentation is tabs, not mixed with space. As an extra measure, I used Sublime's feature to convert indentation to tabs. I also converted it to 4 spaces, but am still getting the same error.

```
#! python3
#randomQuizGenerator.py - Creates quizzes with questions and answers in 
#random order, with the answer key

import random

#The quiz data
#Keys are states and values are their capitals

capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix','Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver','Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee','Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois':'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas':'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine':'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan':'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri':'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada':'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton', 'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe','New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh','North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City','Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence','South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee':'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont':'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia', 'West Virginia': 'Charleston','Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}

#Generate 35 quiz files
for quizNum in range(35):
    #Create the quiz and answer key files
    quizFile = open('capitalsquiz%s.text' % (quizNum + 1), 'w')
    answerKeyFile = open('capitalsquiz_capitalsquiz_answers%s' % (quizNum + 1), 'w')

    #Write out the header for the quiz.
    quizFile.write('Name:\n\nDate:\n\nPeriod\n\n')
    quizFile.write((' ' * 20) + 'State Capitals Quiz (Form %s)' % (quizNum + 1))
    quizFile.write('\n\n')

    #Shuffle the order of the states
    states = list(capitals.keys())
    random.shuffle(states)


    #Loop through all 50 states, making a question for each
    for questionNum in range(50):
        #Get right and wrong answers
        correctAnswer = capitals[states[questionNum]]
        wrongAnswers = list(capitals.values())
        del wrongAnswers[wrongAnswers.index(correctAnswer)]
        wrongAnswers = random.sample(wrongAnswers, 3)
        answerOptions = wrongAnswers + [correctAnswer]
        random.shuffle(answerOptions)

    #Write the question and answer options to the quiz file

    quizFile.write('%s. What is the capital of %s?\n') % (questionNum + 1, states[questionNum])

    for i in range(4):
        quizFile.write(' %s. %s\n' % ('ABCD'[i], answerOptions[i]))
    quizFile.write('\n')


    #Write the answer key to a file
    answerKeyFile.write('%s. %s\n' % (questionNum + 1, 'ACBD'[answerOptions.index(correctAnswer)]))
    quizFile.close()
    answerKeyFile.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure? Look at the code you just posted, clearly line #10 is out of the for loop. Also, avoid using tabs if they are not set to be converted to spaces by your text editor.

Comment: You should be using 4 spaces not tabs.

Comment: @Vicyorus Sorry, formatting mistake when posting on Stackoverflow. In my code, it's aligned and in the for loop. I've updated my code

Comment: @IanAuld I also converted indentation to 4 spaces and it's returning the same error

Comment: I get no error running the edited code except for `capital` not being defined but I assume this is part of a larger program.

Comment: Can you specify exactly, which error you got? Could it be, that the loop itself is out of synch (not the content of the loop)?

Comment: @Juergen "  File "randomQuizGenerator.py", line 29
    for quizNum in range(35):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent"

Comment: You have mixed tabs and spaces, you can see them in the source of your edit

Comment: @Sam: In this case, post also the surrounding code. I would guess, that the problem is there.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Can you elaborate on how you're seeing this? In my editor (using Sublime if that matters), all of my indentation is tabs. I even used the convert indentation to tabs feature in Sublime to be sure. For extra measure, I converted it to spaces as well and it's returning the same error.

Comment: @Sam The problem is not inside the `for` loop. It has to be something outside. Please upload complete code if possible.

Comment: Unless your `random` module really has a `cample` function instead of `sample`, and unless your local python is somehow ok with the missing comma between `'Little Rock'` and `'California'`, you are _not just pasting your code_. Please _just paste it_ without editing.

Comment: @Sam do you still get errors after making the above changes??

Comment: @Useless I've edited to fix those errors, but I am _just pasting my code_. I'm a beginner programmer, so yes, I'm still making mistakes. Any help with the actual question at hand would be appreciated.

Comment: @CRAKC Yes, same error :/

Comment: @Sam Well, that's not normal. Please check this link- https://ideone.com/xGv6LI
I have pasted and compiled your code there. It shows only a runtime error and that's because the file handling methods are denied permission. I don't see where you are getting compilation errors.

Comment: Just pasting doesn't omit or substitute a random cample of characters. Anyway, I now have a script I can run, and I get an exception writing a formatted string - but I see you haven't shown your exception. If it's the same, I'll show you how to fix it. Otherwise, I still haven't reproduced your problem.

Comment: Running this code I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple'` on line 40. I'm unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: @CRAKC Yes, I'm realizing that now. I downloaded the code you compiled and I was returning a different error on unsupported operand types on line 40. Out of curiosity, I copied my exact code, pasted it into a different file, saved and it compiled without giving me the indentation error, only an error on line 40 for unsupported operand types. I'm still not sure what happened here, but it seems to resolved. I just need to correct the other error now

Comment: @Sam There was no indentation error at all. Seems like the `comma` you left out inside `capitals` confused the compiler.

Comment: @IanAuld Out of curiosity, because other people were unable to reproduce the same error, I copied and pasted my exact code into a new file, saved and compiled it and now I only get the same error on line 40 as you mentioned. Running the old file (exact same code, just saved in a different file in the same directory) I'm still getting the unexpected indentation error. I'm not at all sure what's happening

Comment: @CRAKC Nope, that's not it. I fixed that error in my code and I was (and still am) getting the same indentation error. Only when I copied and pasted the code into a new .py file did I stop getting the error.

Comment: Try `diff`ing the files - there must be _something_ different, but maybe the editor's being cute and hiding it from you.

Comment: Run the original file through hexdump, eg. at http://mark0.net/hexdump.html and post the result somewhere. (Or just upload the original file to some place that handles binary files) It'd be interesting to see what caused it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../indent.py", line 40, in <module>
    quizFile.write('%s. What is the capital of %s?\n') % (questionNum + 1, states[questionNum])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Now, the problem in the line shown is that you're trying to write the literal format string:

```
quizFile.write('%s. What is the capital of %s?\n')
```

is a complete expression: it writes that string, with the `%` characters in it, and returns the number of bytes written. This means the rest of the line evaluates as

```
(bytes written)  % (questionNum + 1, states[questionNum])
```

which means you have an int as the left-hand argument, and a tuple as the right-hard argument to `%`. This is what the exception says.

The line should be:

```
quizFile.write('%d. What is the capital of %s?\n' % (questionNum + 1, states[questionNum]))
```

note the `'format' % (tuple)` expression is all inside the `write(...)`.

Comment: It's probably a better idea to just use `format()` method on the string.

Comment: @IanAuld Should I use the `format()` method on the entire string I'm trying to write to the file?

Comment: It's the more modern way - I still prefer the printf-style formatting myself, but that's probably just habit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to indent your `quizFile.write('\n\n')`. Or added wrong idents after it. Identation after it have no meaning, this code cannot be continued in a loop defined above.

Comment: It's indented properly, but I made a mistake when formatting it for Stackoverflow. It's been corrected

Comment: Try to show invisible characters like tabs and spaces in your editor.  Corrected code looks to be ok.